# Trying to create a list in C# whose elements are variations of elements in other lists

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to create a new list in C#. It will have far to many elements to write each element by hand but all of its elements will be made from elements in other lists. As an abridged example, I have

- list A `{"John", "Mary", "Sam"}`
- list B `{"A.", "B.", "C."}`
- list C `{"Smith", "Jones", "Williams"}`

I want to make list D whose elements will each be a string that is equal to the concatenation of an element from A + an element from B + an element from C [in that order]. So list D should be

`{"John C. Williams", "Mary B. Smith", "John A. Williams", ...}`, containing all possible combinations.

The question is how do I create this list since as you can see the list can get too big to write by hand when the 3 initial lists start getting bigger.

Comment: Consider using `yield return` rather than a list - since that may avoid the memory blow out once the inputs get large.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As @mjwills suggested use something like `yield return l1[i] + l2[i] + l3[i]`

Comment: Rather than parallel arrays(?) consider a class to keep related information together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<String> listD = new List<String>(A.Count*B.Count*A.Count);

foreach( String firstName in A )
   foreach( String middle in B )
      foreach( String lastName in C )
          listD.Add( firstName + " " + middle + " " + lastName );
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the Cartesian Product of all the name components, which is what it sounds like you're after.

```
List<String> listD = new List<String>( capacity: listA.Count * listB.Count * listC.Count );
foreach( String firstName in listA )
foreach( String middle in listB )
foreach( String lastName in listC )
{
    listD.Add( firstName + " " + middle + " " + lastName );
}
```

Or using Linq with Tuples to avoid allocation if you only want to iterate:

```
IEnumerable<(String fn, String m, String ln)> names =
    listA.SelectMany( firstName =>
        listB.SelectMany( middle =>
            listC.Select( lastName => ( firstName, middle, lastName ) ) );

foreach( (String fn, String m, String ln) in names )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "{0} {1} {2}", fn, m, ln );
}
```

Comment: But this will not work for very big lists. I mean if lists A,B,C fill the whole RAM, you can't creat list D this way. Not sure if OP wanted that, but he was talking about really big lists.

Comment: @AlKepp That's why I suggested using Linq in my second example, which won't allocate anything (besides the Linq iterator state-machines).

Comment: This also worked! Thank you so much!! I really appreciate the help!!